# How do I generate a new table to a DB using SQL in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'll guess the headline pretty much covers my question, however to elaborate on my question a bit further in order to avoid any confusion, I can say that I have found a ready-made table which is in SQL and it is this SQL I would like to know whether or not it is possible to just paste it into phpmyadmin in order to generate the table ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After selecting the database you want to insert your table into, click the "SQL" tab. Then you can paste your SQL right there and that will generate your table for you - provided the SQL is correct.

If you have any trouble, feel free to post your SQL and we'll have a look.

Comment: I did as you described and it worked ! - thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `import` function on top, select your sql file there. This should create your table which is coded in the sql file.